# Inserting formatted numbers as text in Right to Left MS-Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word, right-to-left

I have `sValA = 10/140/000` string.

Need inserting **10/140/000** as text in a **right-to-left** document.

When I performs below

```
ThisDocument.Bookmarks("Temp_GrandTotal").Range.Text = sValA
```

It returns **000/140/10**

Any helps are appreciated.

Comment: `ThisDocument.Bookmarks("Temp_GrandTotal").Range.Text = StrReverse(sValA)`?

Comment: It returns **01/041/000**! while I need **10/140/000** as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a UDF to swap the parts by a swap character. Then call it like:

```
ThisDocument.Bookmarks("Temp_GrandTotal").Range.Text = SwapParts(sValA,"\")
```

UDF code:

```
Option Explicit

Function SwapParts(ByVal sText As String, ByVal SwapChar As String) As String
    Dim oItems As Variant, oItem As Variant, sOutput As String
    oItems = Split(sText, SwapChar)
    For Each oItem In oItems
        If Len(sOutput) > 0 Then sOutput = SwapChar & sOutput
        sOutput = oItem & sOutput
    Next oItem
    SwapParts = sOutput
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: One possible downside of actually changing the text of the document, is if you ever need to search for something in this format, you will have to reverse the text you want to search for: `000/140/10` instead of `10/140/000`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `LtrRun` method on the `Selection` object, which you can get from the `Range` object:

```
ThisDocument.Bookmarks("Temp_GrandTotal").Range.Select
Selection.LtrRun
```

This tells Word that the direction of this sequence of direction-neutral characters should be left-to-right, unlike the rest of the document.

Comment: Error: `Method or data member not found`, while the `LtrRun` have selected.

Comment: @Tuberose It seems that `LtrRun` exists only on the `Selection`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Sub UpdateRTLBookmark(StrBkMk As String, StrTxt As String)
Dim RngBkMk As Range, RngSel As Range
With ActiveDocument
  If .Bookmarks.Exists(StrBkMk) Then
    Set RngSel = .Selection.Range
    Set RngBkMk = .Bookmarks(StrBkMk).Range
    RngBkMk.Text = StrTxt
    RngBkMk.Select
    Selection.RtlRun
    .Bookmarks.Add StrBkMk, RngBkMk
    RngSel.Select
  End If
End With
Set RngBkMk = Nothing: Set RngSel = Nothing
End Sub
```

which you'd call with code like:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim StrBkMk As String, StrTxt As String
StrBkMk = "Temp_GrandTotal": StrTxt = "10/140/000"
Call UpdateRTLBookmark(StrBkMk, StrTxt)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The advantage of this approach is that you can update the bookmarked range again, if needed.

If you want the Text to be in LTR format, change Selection.RtlRun to Selection.LtrRun. I'd change the macro name, too.

Comment: The document is RTL. In order to force the run to be in left-to-right direction, why should you call `.RtlRun`?

Comment: If you want the Text to be in LTR format, change Selection.RtlRun to Selection.LtrRun. I'd change the macro name, too.